# Angular-google-maps library is not is not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

For angular google I am using following different version of angularjs google maps library. If I use first library,  Please make some zoom-in then click Marker, Map automatically zoom-out, Which I don't want. But with 2nd library it is working correctly. Please find demo corresponding each library. I think 1st newest one, so why it is not working with it,

Please make some zoom-in, then click on marker. In 1st Demo, on clicking it will automatically zoom-out. Which I don't want. But 2nd Demo it working correctly..

1. [angular-google-maps/2.1.5/angular-google-maps.js](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-google-maps/2.1.5/angular-google-maps.js)

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Zc0sQH36sYplKCtdkpM1?p=preview)

```
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.5.0/lodash.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-google-maps/2.1.5/angular-google-maps.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
```

2. [angular-google-maps/2.1.0-X.5/angular-google-maps.js](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-google-maps/2.1.0-X.5/angular-google-maps.js)

[plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/SuqJsAjJOuD8pvJzNBMA?p=preview)

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.5.0/lodash.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-google-maps/2.1.0-X.5/angular-google-maps.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Both are behaving same on plunker though...Clicking on Marker, the marker doesn't zoom at all...

Comment: @Kailas  no Please make some zoom-in then click it will zoom out http://plnkr.co/edit/Zc0sQH36sYplKCtdkpM1?p=preview

Comment: @Kailas Have you got my point..

Comment: ya weird.. don't know why you using the angular google maps... instead of google maps directly? And by the way... now google maps require the auth keys...  '<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<your key here>">'